# (1) near "existsUserInformation": syntax error

Tags: database

```
public class DataBaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "USER DATA";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME_USERSINFO = "UserInformation";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_FIRSTNAME = "FirstNamestring";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_LASTNAME = "LastNamestring";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ADD1 = "Add1string";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ADD2 = "Add2string";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SSNFRST ="SSnfirststring";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SSNLST = "SSnlaststring";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MOBNO = "ContactNostring";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_EMAILID = "emailidstring";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DOB = "Dateofbirthstring";

    public DataBaseClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sqlQueryToCreateUserInformation = "create table if not exists" + TABLE_NAME_USERSINFO +
                "(" + BaseColumns._ID + "integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_FIRSTNAME + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_LASTNAME + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_ADD1 + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_ADD2 + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_SSNFRST + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_SSNLST + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_MOBNO + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_EMAILID + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_DOB + " text not null,"
                + ");";
        db.execSQL(sqlQueryToCreateUserInformation);

    }

    public void insertForm(String FirstNmstring, String LastNmstring, 
            String Add1string ,String Add2string,String SSnfirststring,
            String SSnlaststring, String ContactNostring, String emailidstring, String Dateofbirthstring) {

        String sqlQueryToCreateUserInformation;

        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_FIRSTNAME,FirstNmstring);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_LASTNAME, LastNmstring);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_ADD1, Add1string);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_ADD2, Add2string);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_SSNFRST, SSnfirststring);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_SSNLST, SSnlaststring);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_MOBNO, ContactNostring);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_EMAILID, emailidstring);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_DOB, Dateofbirthstring);

        getWritableDatabase().insert("USER DATA", null, cv);

        }
```

I am executing this code to store my data in SQLite database built in Android phones. When I am executing my code, I am getting an error message that is "(1) near "existsUserInformation": syntax error"

Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: There is a comma at the end of last column (COLUMN_NAME_DOB + " text not null,"  )..please correct that

Comment: I fix this but still getting same error ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space in your string concatenation:

```
"create table if not exists" + TABLE_NAME_USERSINFO
```

results in the string

```
"create table if not existsUserInformation".
```

Just add a space after exists:

```
"create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME_USERINFO.
```

You also have an extra comma at the end of your statement.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked for me ... now its giving some another error ..."(1) AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"...