# (1) near "foodItems": syntax error SQLite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, syntax

Have looked at similar problems and all seem to be reporting either a problem with white space or using existing SQLite reserved words for table name. I have checked both however have found nothing that should be conflicting.

Error:

```
01-14 20:21:26.924: E/SQLiteLog(19622): (1) near "foodItems": syntax error
01-14 20:21:26.924: E/CurrentItems(19622): Could not create or open the database
```

Code:

```
package com.example.foodcalculator;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CurrentItems extends ListActivity {

    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "foodcalculator.db";
    private final String PRODUCT_TABLE = "foodItems";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase foodDB = null;

        try {
            foodDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE,
                    null);

            foodDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + PRODUCT_TABLE
                    + " (barcode String, title String, quantity Double);");

            foodDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + PRODUCT_TABLE
                    + " Values ('564565645665','Beans',1.5);");

            Cursor c = foodDB.rawQuery("SELECT * " + PRODUCT_TABLE, null);

            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"));
                        Double quantity = c.getDouble(c
                                .getColumnIndex("Quantity"));
                        results.add("" + title + ", Quantity: " + quantity);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }

            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Could not create or open the database");
        } finally {
            if (foodDB != null)
                foodDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE);
            foodDB.close();
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.current_inventory);

        final Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanCurrent);
        final Button editInventoryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editItemCurrent);

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddItem.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        editInventoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EditItems.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223028/1-near-existsuserinformation-syntax-error

Comment: i have said i have checked white space, as fair as i am aware and cannot find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor c = foodDB.rawQuery("SELECT * " + PRODUCT_TABLE, null);
```

There's a missing `FROM` there, should be

```
Cursor c = foodDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE, null);
```

You should also be logging your exceptions so you can more easily figure out the exact problem and its location.

Comment: that's worked as far as that error is concerned! now got a list of others errors lol :/ many thanks!